# how to convert a application which is built under WPF 3.0 to 4.5

Tags: wpf

I built an application in WPF 3.0 but I want to switch to WPF 4.5 how it become possible and is there are any issues of switching?

Please guide me

Comment: Take a back up of the project and change the target framework and recompile. If you have **specific** questions post those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Go to `Project -> Properties` Change `target framework` to .NET 4.5.
Visual studio will convert the project to relevant version