# Converting WPF .NET 3 to .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We have a WPF .NET3 forms application written primarily using C#. We was wondering how difficult a process it is to convert everything into .NET4. Is this a difficult task or is it just a standard process like many other conversions from an earlier .NET Framework upto 4.

Comment: Converting the targeted .NET version (in VS) should be straightforward since it's backwards compatible, but remember that the end-user needs to update their version as well.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799406/how-to-convert-a-application-which-is-built-under-wpf-3-0-to-4-5/13799510#13799510) could this be what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to Project -> Properties , under Application Tab -> Change target framework to .NET 4.X.

Visual studio will handle the rest automatically. The only thing you need to think that end-user needs at least the same framework as you used for your project.